# How to do Password and Confirm password validation in Django Forms

Tags: python, django, forms

It's a signup form. When I input different passwords it doesn't show any error. I referred many sites, please help me

```
    from django import forms
    from .models import *
    class signup_form(forms.Form):
          firstname = forms.CharField()
          lastname = forms.CharField()
          email = forms.EmailField()
          GENDER_CHOICES = (
            ('M', 'Male'),
            ('F', 'Female'),
        )
          Qual_choices = (
    ('UG', 'UG'),
    ('PG', 'PG')
    )
          gender = forms.ChoiceField( widget=forms.RadioSelect,choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
          qualification =           forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,choices=Qual_choices)
          Password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
          ConfirmPassword = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

          def clean(self):

               cleaned_data = super(signup_form, self).clean()
               password = cleaned_data.get('Password')
               confirm_password = cleaned_data.get('ConfirmPassword')
               if password and confirm_password:
                     if password != confirm_password:
                     raise forms.ValidationError('Password mismatch')

               return confirm_password
```

Comment: Try to print values for `password` and `confirm_password`. Their values must have been failing the condition `if password and confirm_password:` as the values maybe empty.

Comment: Yes.When I print it's shows nothing.What should I do?

Comment: Most probably, you are not rendering form correctly.

Comment: Show us the template where the form is displayed.

Comment: @JohnGordon`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}


        <center>
            <table>
                {{form.as_table}}
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </center>

</form>
</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 1):

you need to add self before clean_data

```
 def clean_password2(self):

    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
    if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match")
    return password2
```

if the form is validated than do this

```
  if register_form.is_valid():
            user = register_form.save(commit=False)
            user = register_form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = register_form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, 
            password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('some url')
```

Comment: i have updated my code so you can refer to it cause this code is working.

Comment: can you upload the method of you signup view

Comment: `def view(request):

    form = signup_form()
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

    return render(request,'signup.html',{'form':form})`

Comment: i have edited my answer please refer to it and try it once